# Using bash case statement in gitlab ci/cd to set variables

Tags: yaml, switch-statement, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm trying to create a pipeline and set some variables from gitlab based of the git branch, in my case staging, master and everything else branch:

```
---
stages:
  - deploy
  - pre
  - pro

.deployment_env_vars: &deployment_env_vars
  before_script:
    - |
      case "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" in
        staging)
          env='pre'
        ;;
        master)
          env='pro'
        ;;
        *)
          env='dev'
          SSH_HOST=$SSH_HOST_DEV
          SSH_USER=$SSH_USER_DEV
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV
        ;;
      esac
    - project='project'
    - component='api'

variables:

deploy:
  image: python:3.10.10-alpine
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  except:
    - staging
  <<: *deployment_env_vars
  tags:
    - project-api-dev
  before_script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent > /dev/null || ( apk add --update openssh )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan $SSH_HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 664 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

But **$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY**, and **$SSH_HOST** are empty and the pipeline fails because ssh-add try to add a empty key, if i use **$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV** and **$SSH_HOST_DEV** my pipeline works, seems like gitlab bypass the ***)** case, anybody know why?

I'm trying to put a \ before *, like this *) but not works:

```
  case "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" in
    staging)
      env='pre'
    ;;
    master)
      env='pro'
    ;;
    \*)
      env='dev'
      SSH_HOST=$SSH_HOST_DEV
      SSH_USER=$SSH_USER_DEV
      SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_DEV
```

Answer (score 0):

The [merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) docs read:

> If the value associated with the key is a single mapping node, each of its key/value pairs is inserted into the current mapping, **unless the key already exists in it**.

Since `before_script` already exists in the mapping you want to merge into, the `before_script` from `.deployment_env_vars` doesn't get merged. `<<` doesn't do recursive merging.

You should use [`!reference`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) instead.